# Play selected channel solo in VSE?

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to play a channel solo in the VSE, through a shortcut or python? I mean like ex. hide/mute all unselected  channels?

Comment: I don't think so, though it could be possible a python script that mutes unselected channels, and back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solo a track/channel by choosing anything other than 0 in the preview window.

[image: vse solo]

A track higher shows...

[image: vse solo track]

You cannot render out this way however. Also there's an issue with alpha, you can still see below the strips with a crop or other kind of Alpha over enabled. See the cropped image below, you can see the track beneath it.

[image: vse solo alpha]

However if you select all of the strips in that channel and group them together using Ctrl-G key, then the new Metastrip is produced with no alpha over enabled.

[image: vse solo no alpha]

Answer (score 2):

No way to natively hide/mute channels. Only strips:

'H' & 'Alt+H' will mute/hide & unmute/unhide a strip.

'Shift+H & 'Shift + Alt + H" the same, but inverts selection.

However, this add-on can mute/hide entire channels:
https://github.com/venomgfx/addonitos/blob/master/space_sequencer_channel_tools.py
[image: Channel Tools]